# How to drop max-height/overflow properties when Bootstrap column layout changes

Tags: javascript, html

I have two `col` elements in a single Bootstrap `row`/`container`. The left side one is a fixed size, containing a static `table`. The right side one contains a table, like the left, but is dynamically generated based on data retrieved when the page is loaded.

So, of course the right table can be taller than the left one. I've got the right table's `max-height` property set to the left table's height, and `overflow-y: scroll`, figured out in JavaScript. This looks and works great on desktop.

Code gist for reference, HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table id="tblLegend">...</table>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <table id="tblStops">...</table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mxHt = $("#tblLegend").css("height");
    $("#tblStops").css("max-height", mxHt)
                  .css("overflow-y", "scroll");
});
```

However, I'd like to be able to remove the `max-height` (and subsequently, the `overflow-y`) property from the `tblStops` element if the page is displaying in a mobile format, or is resized to a mobile screen's size. In this case, the two tables would be stacked on top of one another vertically, and there would be no need for a separate scroll pane for mobile devices. (Not to mention that an internal scroll pane on mobile is irritating and difficult to control sometimes).

Is there a relatively easy way to do this without resorting to `window.size` or `window.resize` events? I just don't like the idea of having to check for hardcoded screen/window dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the screen size in JavaScript. As you are using JQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
  $("#tblStops").css("max-height", "auto")
                  .css("overflow-y", "auto");
}
```

Auto value will add or remove scroll according to the requirement in overflow. In height minimum height will be applied for content.

NOTE: Might not work with Iphone's.

EDIT: width() will return value based on browsers and for iphone width 700 might not work.

Comment: Yeah, when I turned the JS console on in Chrome, it shows that Bootstrap will automatically stack the two `div`s when the viewport width goes below 768px. Is that the best way to determine whether there should be a scrollbar for that table? It just feels weird, though maybe that's only my instinct talking. Basically trying to figure the best way to determine when the two `col` divs are stacked like that (no longer side by side).

Comment: You are using `col` class which will determine auto width on available space so it will go down below on small screen because of minimum width. You can determine with that width. You can use chrome to find exact width too. Toggle device toolbar is good feature to test and determine screen size for responsiveness in chrome. Once you get the width apply condition or media query to reset max height and overflow property.